# VBA error 424 object in range object

Tags: excel, combobox, range, vba

I'm getting the 424 error in the code below and I can't figure out what's wrong. Basically I'm trying to populate a combobox with data from a column in a table in a different workbook. I was thinking to do this with ranges and automate as much as I can, i.e. I even wanted to pass the combobox object as a variable... But I'm stuck here...

Thanks for your help!

```
Sub PopListBoxTbl(tbl As String)
Dim popv As Range, col As Range
Dim cmb As ComboBox
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Set cmb = UserForm1.ComboBox2
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(path, False, True)
Set sheet = wb.Worksheets(tbl)
Set col = sheet.Range(tbl)
wb.Close
cmb.Clear
For Each popv In col.Cells 'here's the error line
With cmb
    .AddItem popv.Value
End With
Next popv
End Sub
```

Comment: The error should occur on the line `Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Path, False, True)` because there is no `path` set to open any file. The error you are getting on that line is probably due to the fact that you closed the file before reading / grabbing data from that file. You might want to consider moving that line to the end of the sub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as you close the source workbook, your `col` variable is nothing. That's what causes your error - you can't have a `Range` object referring to a range in a closed workbook. Just close it after you've populated the control, or load the data into an array first.

Comment: Thanks guys! it worked. Had no idea I couldn't have a Range object referring to a range in a closed workbook.